# curl in raspbian shell

Tags: linux, sh

How to save information from `curl` response to a variable? I tried some ways, but nothing worked and I don't know what to do. I wanted to do sh file which writes actual USD exchange rate, the API link is: http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/usd/ and that information is between `<MID></MID>`

I'v tried

```
var = curl http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/usd
```

also something like

```
curl http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/usd >> var
```

Answer (score 1):

Using command substitution

```
var=$(curl http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/usd)
```

Comment: how can i take from it only this "mid"

Comment: @rickrickardo : (Lucy!!!)  edit your question to show what you mean. We need to see sample input data and required output from that same data. Use the `{}` from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to give good formatting like `code/data/output/errMsgs`. (etc) when editing the body of your question above. Good luck.

Comment: Output: `{"table":"A","currency":"dolar amerykański","code":"USD","rates":[{"no":"043/A/N
BP/2023","effectiveDate":"2023-03-02","mid":4.4002}]}`. I want from it only that value after `"mid"` (i want put 4.4002 into variable).

Comment: **edit your question** (Don't put essential information to the understanding your problem in comments (please) ). Good luck.

Comment: Look into `jq` to parse json.